# Run PS-Script after job is done on 3 instances - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, powershell, jobs, instance

I have backup jobs running on a server with 3 instances.

Link to script: https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html

The solution I found for the other 2 servers with only once instance was to create a job which has the backup scripts as steps via TSQL and then simply runs the PowerShell script.

Is there a way to do this on a multi-instance server?

Server is running SQL Server 2012

Comment: I don't understand.  Each instance of SQL Server will have it's own SQL Agent, just create the backup scripts in each instance.  If you are running the jobs from Task Manager then just add multiple steps, one for each instance.

Comment: running the job in SQL managment studio. what you are talking about is my question, where can i do this easily? why task manager? is has to be scheduled

Comment: You have the jobs visible in SQL Agent?  You just need to go to each one and add a schedule to the job so it will run on it's own.  Ola's scripts may create the jobs but it doesn't create schedules for them.

Comment: yeah but I need all the jobs done on 3 instances and THEN run a powershellscript.

Comment: so it's a dependency issue?  The easiest method is to pick one server and have it launch the job on the other servers and then run the powershell script when they are all done.

Comment: ok yeah I think I know now. so you mean running a job which runs steps which connect to all every instance, backup, next instance, ... ..., Powershellskript. I guess via TSQL for backups on every instance ?

Comment: you should include @JonathanFite in your comment if you want him to get notified

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options on how you could handle this...

1. Create a Scheduled Task on that server that contains a PowerShell script. The first part of that script contains a `workflow` that would iterate over each instance and call the backup job on each instance. Use a `foreach -parallel` would allow all the jobs to start at one time. You would then need to script out a while loop to wait and see that all jobs have completed. Then the end of that PowerShell script just call the code you need to run.
2. Pick an instance and use it as a "central" location to actually run the backups against each instance. You could utilize linked servers to remotely call Ola' scripts. This would offer a bit more control and ease of management because you would know once the command finished the backup for that instance are complete. Your last step would just be your PowerShell script.
3. Leave each backup job on the given instance. Add a scheduled task that calls your PowerShell script, but at the start of that script check to make sure a recent backup has been done. If not, just stop the script. Schedule that task to run between an the average end time of the backup jobs until a given a few hours later. This would ensure at some point it will find that the backups on all instances are current, then execute your code.